# StrToDate throwing econverterror

Tags: delphi

I have the following piece of code

```
aDate := StrToDate(date, GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT));


function GetLocaleFormatSettings(ALCID: integer): TFormatSettings;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
begin
  if (ALCID <> gLCID) then
  begin
    gLCID := ALCID;
    gFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(gLCID);
    // TKR - 3/25/10 - C13689: TwoDigitYearCenturyWindow is not set via GetLocalFormatSettings
    gFormatSettings.TwoDigitYearCenturyWindow := 75;
  end;
  Result := gFormatSettings;
end;
```

It works perfectly fine but sometimes when i change the system date format to dd/mm/yyyy it crashes and throws the exception. Other times it just takes the values without any issues. From some other SO thread i found out that we need to set the **DateSeparator** properly. but is it possible to set it at runtime based on user settings?

Note: This happens only when i change the date settings after i run my application. If i close the application and execute it, i am not getting any errors.

Comment: You should try VarToDate

Comment: What Delphi version are you using, and does it include VCL source? Have you tried enabling debug DCUs and actually debugging the issue to determine where the problem lies?

Comment: I am using Delphi XE and yes it includes VCL source

Comment: @SirRufo should be VarToDateTIME? ;)

Comment: @iPath Yepp (i have lost time) :o)

Comment: @SirRufo: It actually worked